# Use the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition to determine a limit

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{6n^{3}-3(\cos(2n+2))^{2}}{3n^{3}-3n^{2}+2} = 2$ using the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition.

This is what I have so far:

\begin{gather}
\left| \frac{6n^{3}-3(\cos(2n+2))^{2}}{3n^{3}-3n^{2}+2} - 2 \right| < \epsilon, \\
\left| \frac{6n^{3}-3(\cos(2n+2))^{2}-6n^{3}+6n^{2}-4}{3n^{3}-3n^{2}+2} \right| < \epsilon, \\
\left| \frac{-3(\cos(2n+2))^{2}+6n^{2}-4}{3n^{3}-3n^{2}+2} \right| < \epsilon
\end{gather}

Please advise me on how to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\dots < \epsilon$"?

Comment: Well from my understanding, the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition is as follows: $ \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n} = L \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq N, |a_{n} - L| < \epsilon $

Comment: Your definition is correct. I was wondering if you mean that ... is smaller than any $\epsilon$ for all $n\geq$ some $N_\epsilon$; if yes, that could be stated more clearly

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I'm unsure how to state that more clearly, though.

Comment: Write something like: „Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\dots<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N.“

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$|-3(\cos(2n+2))^{2}+6n^{2}-4|< 3+6n^2+4 \\
|3n^{3}-3n^{2}+2|> 3n^{3}-3n^{2}-2$$

Also, for $n>4$ you have
$$3n^{3}-3n^{2}-2> 2n^3$$

Comment: How did the $6n^{2}$ become a $6n^{3}$ in the top line?

Comment: @Kirsten Typo, fixed. Ty